# How to monitor/performance Jenkins server?

Tags: performance, jenkins

How to monitor Jenkins server and check the performance of the server. is there any tool to check regular or anything else.

Answer (score 0):

I guess "Monitoring Jenkins with JavaMelody" is the common answer on this question. But there are plenty of monitoring plugins for Jenkins. Here is great plugin's review: https://medium.com/@pavithra_38952/managing-and-monitoring-jenkins-6df681813c0a

And/or you can monitor it as a regular server by using some monitoring common monitoring tool( zabbix, nagios, prometeus).

I hope it will help you)